# не работает border b porder-radius

Tags: html, css

создал таблицу, и для четирех крайних полей написал CSS

```
th:first-child {
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
}

th:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 4px 0 0;
}


tr:last-child td:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 0;
}

tr:last-child td:first-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 0 4px;
}
```

Почему, когда ниже пишу етот СSS рамка в этих клетках прямоугольная?

```
th, td {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #d8dbde;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Comment: Потому что это таблица. К тому же, ты вообще не туда вешаешь радиусы.

Comment: @Qwertiy а как тогда таблице это применить?

Comment: `````table`````?

Comment: Может поможет - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1113867/265406